# regex to identify specific character

Tags: java, regex, regression

I need read a pdf and need to extract data from that.

Data format is some thing like that

Pattern 1:

```
Impuestos indirectos excluidos. 
Forma de pago: 60 días F.F Según condiciones generales de contratación. 
FIRMA: Juan Rubio FECHA: 28/09/2021
```

Pattern 2:

```
Impuestos indirectos excluidos. 
Forma de pago: 60 días F.F. 
 Según condiciones generales de contratación. 
FIRMA: Juan Rubio FECHA: 20/09/202
```

from that I have to find out 60 días F.F.

I tried in this way `\W*(Forma de pago):(\\s)\W*` , which is not working

I am very new to regex and java. Please note "Forma de pago" is fixed in each pdf.

In word requirement is : read anything after "Forma de pago:" till "60 días F.F", means 3 elements only after "Forma de pago:"

can any one help on that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String regex = "\\bForma\\s+de\\s+pago:\\s*(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+)";
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hLybjI/1). *Details*:

- `\bForma` - a whole word `Forma` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `de` - `de` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `pago:` - a `pago:` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces and then two occurrences of one or more whitespaces and one or more non-whitespace chars.